# Displaying an attribute of a class if that attribute is not defined in __init__?

Tags: python, class, attributes, instance

```
class MyClass:

def __init__(self,n):
    self.x = n

def set_y(self):
    self.y = self.x * 2

obj = MyClass(2)
obj.set_y
obj.__dict__
```

output:

```
{'x': 2}
```

---

My question is, although the instance method `set_y` is called, `y` is not displayed by `obj.__dict__`. Is it because `y` is not defined inside `__init__`?

Comment: You never *called* `set_y`. *Calling* is done with parentheses().

Comment: Oh crap. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `set_y` is not called as you forgot the brackets.

Should be:

```
obj.set_y()
```